# ListView CustomAdapter getView is not calling

Tags: android, android-listview

1. Below is my code, here i am getting response..

   ```
      Fetching Data from server in josn


          getRequest();
                      list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
                      list.setAdapter(adapter);
                      list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                          @Override
                          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                                  int position, long id) {

                          }
                      });

      //

              private void getRequest(){
                      Thread trd = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                          @Override
                          public void run() {
                              DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                              HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
                              HttpResponse httpResponse = null;

      //


                              try{
                                  Log.d("Get top called","try block");
                                  HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
                                  httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                                  httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                                  response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
                                  if(response!=null){
                                      try{
                                          HashMap<String, String> defaultSongsDetails;
                                          songs = new JSONArray(response);
                                          JSONObject jsonObject;
                                          for(int i=0;i<songs.length();i++){

                                              defaultSongsDetails = new HashMap<String, String>();

                                              String title,artist,language,imageUrl,songUrl,vocalUrl,duration=null;
                                              String sdCardPathOfImage,sdCardPathOfOriginalSong,sdCardPathOfVocalSong=null;

                                              jsonObject = songs.getJSONObject(i);

                                              title = jsonObject.getString(SONG_TITLE);
                                              defaultSongsDetails.put("song_title",title);

                                              artist = jsonObject.getString(SONG_ARTIST);
                                              defaultSongsDetails.put("song_artist",artist);




                                              language = jsonObject.getString(SONG_LANGUAGE);
                                              defaultSongsDetails.put("song_language",language);

                                              duration = jsonObject.getString(SONG_DURATION);
                                              defaultSongsDetails.put("song_duration",duration);

                                              imageUrl = jsonObject.getString(SONG_THUMBNAL);
                                              songUrl = jsonObject.getString(SONG_DOWNLOAD_URL);
                                              vocalUrl = jsonObject.getString(SONG_VOCAL_URL);

                                              String thumbnail=null;
                                              int cutImg = imageUrl.lastIndexOf('/');
                                              if (cutImg != -1) {
                                                  thumbnail = imageUrl.substring(cutImg + 1);
                                              }
                                              sdCardPathOfImage = basepath + "/songs/" + thumbnail;
                                              defaultSongsDetails.put("song_thumbnail", sdCardPathOfImage);
   String fileName=null;    int cut = songUrl.lastIndexOf('/');    if (cut != -1) {    fileName = songUrl.substring(cut + 1);    }
   ```

   sdCardPathOfOriginalSong = basepath+"/songs/" + fileName;
                                                  defaultSongsDetails.put("song_original_path",
   sdCardPathOfOriginalSong);
       String vocalFileName=null;    int cutVocal = songUrl.lastIndexOf('/');    if (cut != -1) {    vocalFileName =
   songUrl.substring(cutVocal + 1);    }    sdCardPathOfVocalSong =
   basepath+"/songs/" + vocalFileName;
                                                  defaultSongsDetails.put("song_vocal_path", sdCardPathOfVocalSong);
   //Adding Hashmap to ArrayList
                                                  defaultSongsDetailList.add(defaultSongsDetails);
                                              adapter = new CustomList(JsonActivity.this,defaultSongsDetailList);
                      }catch (Exception e){    e.printStackTrace();    }    }    }catch (Exception e) {    e.printStackTrace();    }    }
   });    trd.start();
                      }

   ```
      //CustomList Adapter class


              public class CustomList extends ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String, String>>{
                  private final Activity context;

                  private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songList;
                  public CustomList(Activity context,
                                         ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songList) {
                      super(context, R.layout.list_item_view, songList);
                      this.context = context;
                      this.songList = songList;
                  }
                  @Override
                  public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
                      LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
                      View rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_view, null, true);
                      TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.title);
                      ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.list_image);
                      TextView txtArtist = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.artist);
                      TextView txtDuration = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.duration);

                      System.out.println(" title ** "+songList.get(position).get("song_title")+" duration **
   ```

   "+songList.get(position).get("song_duration")
                          +" thumb ** "+songList.get(position).get("song_thumbnail")+" language **
   "+songList.get(position).get("song_language"));

   ```
                      txtArtist.setText(songList.get(position).get("song_title"));
                      txtDuration.setText(songList.get(position).get("song_duration"));

                      File file = new File(songList.get(position).get("song_thumbnail"));
                      Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
                 imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(defaultFilePath));
                          imageView.setImageURI(uri);
                      txtTitle.setText(songList.get(position).get("song_language"));

                      return rowView;
                  }
              }


      Any help would be appreciated...
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
 //Fetching Data from server in josn
        getRequest();

        gAdapter = new BaseAdapter(HomeJsonActivity.this, defaultSongsDetailList);;
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        gAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        list.setAdapter(gAdapter);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
            }
        });

private void getRequest() {
        Thread trd = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
                HttpResponse httpResponse = null;

                try {
                    Log.d("Get top called", "try block");
                    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
                    httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                    httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                    response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
                    if (response != null) {
                        try {
                            HashMap<String, String> defaultSongsDetails;
                            songs = new JSONArray(response);
                            JSONObject jsonObject;
                                defaultSongsDetails = new HashMap<String, String>();

                                String title, artist, language, imageUrl, songUrl, vocalUrl, duration = null;
                                String sdCardPathOfImage, sdCardPathOfOriginalSong, sdCardPathOfVocalSong = null;

                                jsonObject = songs.getJSONObject(i);

                                title = jsonObject.getString(SONG_TITLE);
                                defaultSongsDetails.put("song_title", title);

                                artist = jsonObject.getString(SONG_ARTIST);
                                defaultSongsDetails.put("song_artist", artist);

                                language = jsonObject.getString(SONG_LANGUAGE);
                                defaultSongsDetails.put("song_language", language);

                                duration = jsonObject.getString(SONG_DURATION);
                                defaultSongsDetails.put("song_duration", duration);

                                imageUrl = jsonObject.getString(SONG_THUMBNAL);
                                songUrl = jsonObject.getString(SONG_DOWNLOAD_URL);
                                vocalUrl = jsonObject.getString(SONG_VOCAL_URL);

                                String thumbnail = null;
                                int cutImg = imageUrl.lastIndexOf('/');
                                if (cutImg != -1) {
                                    thumbnail = imageUrl.substring(cutImg + 1);
                                }
                                sdCardPathOfImage = basepath + "/songs/" + thumbnail;
                                defaultSongsDetails.put("song_thumbnail", sdCardPathOfImage);
                                String fileName = null;
                                int cut = songUrl.lastIndexOf('/');
                                if (cut != -1) {
                                    fileName = songUrl.substring(cut + 1);
                                }
                                sdCardPathOfOriginalSong = basepath + "/songs/" + fileName;
                                defaultSongsDetails.put("song_original_path", sdCardPathOfOriginalSong);

                                String vocalFileName = null;
                                int cutVocal = songUrl.lastIndexOf('/');
                                if (cut != -1) {
                                    vocalFileName = songUrl.substring(cutVocal + 1);
                                }
                                sdCardPathOfVocalSong = basepath + "/songs/" + vocalFileName;
                                defaultSongsDetails.put("song_vocal_path", sdCardPathOfVocalSong);

                                defaultSongsDetailList.add(defaultSongsDetails);
                            }

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        trd.start();

    }

//Custom Base Adapter Class

public class BaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songList;

    public BaseAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list) {
        this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.songList = list;
        for (HashMap hh : songList) {
            System.out.println("**** hh ***" + hh);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return songList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return songList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View rowView;
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            rowView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_view, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.title = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            holder.thumb = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.list_image);
            holder.artist = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.artist);
            holder.duration = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.duration);

            rowView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            rowView = convertView;
            holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
        }
        holder.title.setText(songList.get(position).get("song_title"));
        File file = new File(songList.get(position).get("song_thumbnail"));
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        holder.thumb.setImageURI(uri);
        holder.artist.setText(songList.get(position).get("song_artist"));
        holder.duration.setText(songList.get(position).get("song_duration"));

        System.out.println(" title ** " + songList.get(position).get("song_title") + " duration ** " + songList.get(position).get("song_duration")
                + " thumb ** " + songList.get(position).get("song_thumbnail") + " language ** " + songList.get(position).get("song_language"));

        return rowView;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        public ImageView thumb;
        public TextView title, duration, artist;
    }
}
```

Comment: need some help, please check the code once and let me know where i am doing mistake.....its urgent. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try using this : LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); and also place : View rowView = view; if(rowView ==null){ rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_view, null)}